# Spring data when database not know previously

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In my case the database name comes in the request, and i am create the new HikariDataSource(put it to the pool, and take it from here next time). After used JdbcTemplate.

But... is it possible to use spring data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can create a `DataSource` that is just a wrapper around the real `DataSource` which you set once you gathered the necessary information.

Comment: Thanks for idea, now i am have decorator for DataSource.